# django model with two generic (content_type) foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-models, generics

I'm trying to create a mapping table between two generic (content_type) references, one for "agents" and one for "resources".

So I take the usual way I make a generic foreign key :

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
resource = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

And I try to make a model with two.

```
agent_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
agent_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
agent = generic.GenericForeignKey('agent_content_type', 'agent_object_id')

resource_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
resource_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
resource = generic.GenericForeignKey('resource_content_type', 'resource_object_id')
```

But this now throws up the following errors :

> myapp.mymodel: Accessor for field
>   'resource_content_type' clashes with
>   related field
>   'ContentType.mymodel_set'. Add a
>   related_name argument to the
>   definition for
>   'resource_content_type'.

And similar for the agent.

What's going on here? And what should I do?

cheers

phil

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried doing what the error message tells you to do - add a related_name argument?

```
agent_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='mymodel_agent')
```

Edit:
The reason why it happens is that every time you define a foreign key, Django automatically gives the target model an attribute to do the reverse lookup. By default, it gives this the name of the related table + `'_set'` - so if your `article` table has an FK to `section`, `section` will get an `article_set` attribute for the reverse lookup.

Now if you have two FKs in the same model pointing at the same target model, Django will try and give them *both* the `foo_set` attribute, leading to a collision. Hence the error message, which tells you to set the related_name attribute manually.

Comment: thanks, that works. But I was hoping someone could explain why. Or rather, why the ambiguity appears when I have two generic foreign keys but not one?

Comment: Edited to add the explanation.